# Issue parsing JSON for use as data in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, json, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to create a chart using highcharts with dates on the x-axis.
I'm using the following example from the Highcharts website as it is almost exactly what I am trying to achieve. 
Using getJson I am getting json from a URL in this format:

```
[[Date.UTC(2016,04,29),3],[Date.UTC(2016,04,30),1],[Date.UTC(2016,05,02),4]]
```

As you can see it is similar to the format used in the example. However I get the following error from getJson:

```
angular.js:12416 SyntaxError: Unexpected token D in JSON at position 2
```

I don't think Date.UTC is the issue, as when I remove it I still get an error for the next character "(".
When I remove the getJson function and simply hardcode the above values into data, exactly as it is formatted above, the chart renders perfectly. I don't understand how it works when I hardcode it but doesn't if not.

The code is as follows (exactly like in the official highcharts example really)

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8181/graphData', function (data) {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Visitors per day'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Num people'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: data
        }]
    });
});
```

});

Comment: `[[Date.UTC(2016,04,29),3],[Date.UTC(2016,04,30),1],[Date.UTC(2016,05,02),4]]` isn't valid JSON. JSON only supports primitive types, not dates or JS objects. Are you sure that's what you're getting from your data source? Can you post the raw JSON? Or the URL you're getting it from, if it's a public source?

Comment: Also, "Date.UTC is the issue, as when I remove it I still get an error for the next character "("" makes sense because `[[(2016,04,29),3], ...` wouldn't be valid JSON either.

Comment: Hi Anthony. Yes that's definitely what i'm getting as i'm just returning JSON from a custom Spring controller. I understand, but if it is unvalid then why does a getJson on this [URL as provided on the highcharts site](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?) work? Shouldn't this be invalid JSON also? Thanks!

Comment: That URL is definitely not returning valid JSON, looks like a bug on the Highcharts site.

Comment: It looks like the data is generated from code in this folder here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/data. But a lot of these samples don't produce valid JSON.

Comment: @AnthonyE it's not a Bug, it's a JSONP-Resource (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)